# How to create a program that allows user to decide the number of Scanner input and then divides Scanners into arrays of positive and negative numbers?

Tags: java, arrays

```
package nizovi;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nizovi {

private static String array;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
    int k = sc.nextInt();
    int[] pos =new int[k];
    int[] neg = new int [k];
    Scanner n= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of members of array:");
    int members = n.nextInt();
    for (int i=k;i>0;){
         Scanner numb= new Scanner (System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter number:");
          int num=numb.nextInt();
          if (broj >=0){
              pos[num]=n.nextInt();

          }
          else{
              neg[num]=n.nextInt();


          }
    }
}
}
```

I am using for loop and I am confused how to add more numbers into it because if I leave array command in for loop it defines it every time with the different scanner .Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: Maybe you could share your tries ? Because yes, this is a bad explanation ;)

Comment: done,as you can see I did a really bad job here

Comment: THe rule is : one scanner per input, so as you read only from System.in, use only on scanner, try this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First : use one `Scanner` per input source, so here just one not 3

Then, you need to it by steps, you do a lot of useless things

- ask the number of numbers you want to input `k`
- create the arrays
- ask `k` times the user to input a value
- from the value insert in one array of the other

But you'll have zeros in your array, because you create 2 arrays of size `k` but enter only `k` elements, so you'll have `k` zeros in total in your arrays, use `List` to have only what you need

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of members of array:");
int k = scanner.nextInt();

int[] pos = new int[k];
int[] neg = new int[k];

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    int numberUser = scanner.nextInt();
    if (numberUser > 0) {
        pos[i] = numberUser;
    } else {
        neg[i] = numberUser;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pos));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(neg));
```

Comment: thank you soo much. This did the job and I think that I kind of understand how arrays work now.

Answer (score 0):

> Scanner numb= new Scanner (System.in);

That statement ... is simply useless.

You already defined a valid scanner once, further up, named `n`.

You only should:

- use a more meaningful name, like `scannerForUserInput` instead of `n`.
- and then, whenever you want to read from the uer, you use **that** instance.

There is simply no need to define a new scanner for each new input data.